# Why the iterator never ends?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, iterator

I set a iterator to create two categories of feature class, and then join and dissolve them. The calculation works fine. However, the running result never shows completion even when the calculation finishes (show in the 2nd pic).

I tested the model by replacing the iterator with one feature class and changing the outputs' names from "%Name%" to "aa". The model finished without any problem. Therefore I guess the problem lies in the iterator.

I cannot understand why the model comes back to the iterator again when the calculation finishes. How could I solve it? Or it is a bug?

[image: model]

[image: run result]

Comment: Question - if you Validate your model (the checkmark) and rerun the model, does it still complete without showing the progress bar being completed? I've seen this before when you setup an iterator, run the model, an error occurs, make a change to the model to fix the error, then rerun the model without validating again.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Yes, I've validated the model and it still complete without showing completion...

Comment: If you are scrolled down to the last log message, it is saying the the last tool to run is the Iterate Feature Classes - but the last tool to run should be your Dissolve.  Perhaps there is an issue with the preconditions of your model.  Did you happen to setup the model to work on one Feature Class first, then replaced that with the iterator?

Comment: Yes. I tried to replace the iterator with one feature class and changed the outputs name from "%Name%" to "aa". The model finished without any problem. I cannot understand why the model comes back to the iterator again when the calculation finishes.

Comment: Use the Connect tool to make a precondition from the selected feature class of the iterator (green oval), to both of the Clip operations (rectangles).  When you connect them, select precondition.  Change your output back to %Name%, and validate the model.  Once validated, rerun the model.

Comment: I tried precondition as you said for both models. After the validation, the steps from the two clips remain white, for both models. In the model with the iterator, I found that it has run 8 times and I have 7 feature classes.